# 'erdas apollo how to enable this service'?

Tags: erdas-apollo

We have installed ERDAS Apollo, and when we open the welcome page it tells us

> "you've setup ERDAS APOLLO 2011, v11.0 successfully"

but test Sample HTTP requests give an error, for example when test a WFS request:

```
 .../vector/ATLANTA_VECTOR?version=1.0.0&service=WFS&request=GetCapabilities&'
```

We got the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot construct provider ATLANTA_VECTOR. The construction of the provider ATLANTA_VECTOR has already failed.Failure was due to The provider ATLANTA_VECTOR is unknown or more probably, the license is either invalid or does not enable this service!!
```

How can we enable this service?

Answer (score 1):

Ensure that you've correctly licensed Erdas Apollo 2011. On your server open the ERDAS-NET Licensing app, which should have been installed with Erdas Apollo 2011. Ensure that the ERDAS Apollo license displays in the local folder.  For example, under "Erdas Apollo Advantage" 1 license should available and in use, and it should not be expired.

If you have not yet licensed the product be sure to using File --> Load License File and navigate to the license file provided by Erdas. For licensing questions contact sgilicense@intergraph.com.